# Flutter using Base64 or other encoder/decoder for MP3

Tags: flutter

I have some mp3 file and i want to encode/decoding them to using in application, i search approximately all of packages and libraries in [pub.dev](https://pub.dev) but i can't find somethings to do that, how can help me to use this feature in flutter applications?

Comment: base64Decode() and base64Encode() from the import 'dart:io' package

Comment: @Andrew can i encode or decode mp3 with that?

Comment: I've only tried with images, but I don't see why not